# Can we store org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession object in Blob?

Tags: java, websocket, blob

I have tried to store to convert it in `BLOB`. However, I am facing issue due to `WsSession` is non-serialized class and trying to convert it in byte Array.

Is there any way I can store `WsSession` object in `BLOB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If the class is not serializable, it means there are contents which cannot be fully restored, once the class is deserialized. The session is representing an absconding state between a server and a client, therefore it does not make sense to store it in a database.